# Unobtrusive horizontal scrolling with CSS and jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

One of my most favorite websites is that of the [Oxford Hotel](http://www.hotel-oxford.ro/) in Romania.

I like the simplicity of the site and how it flows. I am trying to create a similar scrolling effect using jquery and I've been somewhat successful to a point. My trouble is with css... I am not a wizard in that department.

Anyway,...my questions!

**1.** How can I first make sure that the ".box" class will be in the center of the page when the corresponding link is clicked? Right now it positions itself on the left.

**2.** Then, how can I tweak this code so that the user only can see the width of the screen and not the browser scroller/the rest of my ".box" divs?

Refer to the oxford link if you need to see an example of what I'd like to achieve.

This is a portion of my current CSS.

```
body {
background: #f2f2f2;
text-align:left;
color:#666;
font-size:14px;
font-family:georgia, 'time new romans', serif;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
}

#menu {
background: #333333;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0;
border: 1px solid #000;
clear: both;
float: left;
font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin: 0;
padding: 18px;
z-index: 500;
filter: alpha(opacity=75);
opacity: .75;
}

#menu ul{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#menu ul li{
list-style-type: none;
color: #777;
display: inline;
margin: 0;
padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

#menu ul li a{
text-decoration: none;
list-style-type: none;
color: #777;
display: inline;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#menu ul li a:hover{
text-decoration: none;
list-style-type: none;
color: #fff;
display: inline;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#container {
position: absolute;
top: 120px; 
width: 70000px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.box {
background: white;
border: 3px dashed #f2f2f2;
width: 600px;
float: left;
font-size: 10px;
line-height: 15px;
margin: 0;
padding: 5px 30px 30px 30px;
}
```

Comment: It's pretty impressive how the hotel managed to get that working without Javascript.

Comment: @zneak: they actually **do** use JS for the smooth scrolling part.

Comment: @BalusC: I meant that if you disable Javascript, it still works. No smooth scrolling, but still works.

Answer (score 4):

Your CSS contains a lot of unnecessary stuff and is not really [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)-flavored, so it's hard to nail down the root cause of your problem. To start, you can get it to work in a JS-disabled environment with help of fragment identifiers (`<a href="#someid">` with `<div id="#someid">`). The remnant of the magic is done with `overflow: hidden` (so that "other" boxes don't show up) and `position: relative` (so that the element knows where it is relatively to be positioned to).

Well, here's an SSCCE so that you have something to get started with. Just copy'n'paste'n'run it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 2573478</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#menu a').click(function() {
                    $('#boxes').animate({
                        left: -300 * $('.box').index($(this.hash)) // 300 is width of single box.
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            #container {
                position: relative;
                width: 300px;
                height: 300px;
                border: 1px solid black;
                overflow: hidden; /* So that #boxes doesn't appear in full glory. */
            }
            #boxes {
                position: relative;
                width: 900px; /* 3 boxes of each 300px makes 900px. */
            }
            #container .box {
                float: left;
                width: 300px;
                height: 300px;
            }
            #box1 { background: #fcc; }
            #box2 { background: #cfc; }
            #box3 { background: #ccf; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="boxes">
                <div id="box1" class="box">box1</div>
                <div id="box2" class="box">box2</div>
                <div id="box3" class="box">box3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#box1">box1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#box2">box2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#box3">box3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can find here a [live example](http://jsbin.com/ipida). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are in luck, friend. I just yesterday released a new jQuery plugin that does this very thing:

http://www.simplesli.de

I've tried to make it as simple as possible to set up, but basically, in each slide, you can create a `div` in any way you like. Best of luck!

Comment: Link in answer dead.